# This metal oxide resistor is first in line after mains

Tags: resistors, identification

[image]

This resistor reads yellow purple gold gold white:

[image]

It is the first component after Mains L in, in parallel with the choke, safety X capacitor, etc.

It reads yellow violet gold gap gold white. I cannot identify the bands with online calculators. What could it be?

In the picture of the components the device is lower right, and it is marked  for ZNR1. Under the big capacitor is the four-diode bridge. The card is a Netgear wall wart.

Comment: please post a clearer picture ... have you measured the resistance of that component??

Comment: Heck ! The component was wrapped in a black shrinkwrap marked 125 degrees C. I just remembered.

Comment: I have not desoldered it yet to measure the resistance.

Answer (score 2):

The component is marked F1 on the board. This looks like a fusible resistor of 4.7Ω 5%. The white band could be a manufacturer-specific code for temperature coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Yellow**=4, **Purple**=7, first-**Gold**-line= *0.1, second-**Gold**-line=5%-tollerance

So what you have is a 4.7 ohm resistor with 5% tollerance.

It looks like a 0.5W resistor by the way..